# How to send cookie and phpssid with urllib2 in python?

Tags: python, cookies

I wonder how can I send cookie and phpssid with urllib2 in python?
Actually I want to read a page I've logged in with my browser, but when I try to read it with this script I encounter a text which seems to say that you've missed something.
My script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://mywebsite.com/sub/create.php?id=20')
content = f.read()
file = open('file.txt', 'w')
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

The error message I save instead of the real page :

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/number/domains/1number.com/public_html/s4/app/mywidgets.php:1) in /home/number/domains/1number.com/public_html/s4/app/mywidgets.php on line 23

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/number/domains/1number.com/public_html/s4/app/mywidgets.php:1) in /home/number/domains/1number.com/public_html/s4/app/mywidgets.php on line 23

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/number/domains/1number.com/public_html/s4/app/mywidgets.php:1) in /home/number/domains/1number.com/public_html/s4/lib/webservice.php on line 0
```

What is the exact problem?(Please give me a simple way to implement what I want)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the SID, one of the ways to send that is as part of the query string, and you're already doing that. At least I assume that's what the `id=20` part of your URL is.

For cookies, everything you want is in [`cookielib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html).

Just creating a `CookieJar` to use for a session with the server is trivial. If you want to import cookies from your browser, there are three possibilities:

1. If your browser uses the old Netscape cookie file format, you can use `FileCookieJar`.
2. If your browser uses a sqlite database (as at least Firefox and Safari/Chrome do), use the `sqlite3` module to read it, and populate a `CookieJar` manually.
3. If worst comes to worst, copy and paste the cookies from your browser into your script as hardcoded strings and popular a `CookieJar` manually.

If you don't want to read the docs on how to use `cookielib`, just see [the examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#examples) at the end, which show how to use a `CookieJar` with `urllib2`, which is exactly what you want to do.

If you have a problem, read the docs.

Meanwhile, what you're showing us are (a) warnings, not errors, and (b) obviously a problem on the server side, not your script. The server should never be spewing out a bunch of warnings and an otherwise-blank page. If you, or one of your coworkers, is responsible for the server code, that needs to be fixed first (and your current simple Python script can serve as a great regression test case).

Comment: Can you implement my purpose in what you explained?
I tested but the same result.

    #!/usr/bin/python
    import urllib2
    from cookielib import CookieJar, DefaultCookiePolicy
    policy = DefaultCookiePolicy(
        rfc2965=True, strict_ns_domain=DefaultCookiePolicy.DomainStrict,
        blocked_domains=["ads.net", ".ads.net"])
    cj = CookieJar(policy)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    r = opener.open("http://1number.com/s4/create.php?id=20")
    content = r.read()
    file = open('file.html', 'w')
    file.write(content)
    file.close()

Comment: @Rootkit98: First of all, it's impossible to read code written in a comment. If it doesn't belong in your question, post it somewhere like http://pastebin.com and post a link here. Second, SO is not a place to find people to write your code for you. Finally, as I explained in the answer, there is clearly a problem with the server. Is this a server that you or someone you work with maintains? If so, that's what you need to debug. Show the code for that, and show your attempts to debug it, or nobody will be able to help.